# Can Azure Functions Durable Orchestrator call methods that aren't activity triggers?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have some functionality in an azure durable function that requires the use of generic params. Since activity triggers don't support the use of generic params, I wrote the function as a non-async static method and called it directly from the orchestrator. I am not receiving an error, but I am seeing the warning `Activity function named [myMethodName] does not exist. Did you mean [someActivityFunction]?`

Does this imply that I should not call my static method from the orchestrator?

If I cannot use code isn't an activity trigger, how can I call a generic method within my durable function?

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-orchestrations?tabs=csharp#features-and-patterns), Orchestrators either call Sub Orchestrators or ActivityTriggers, my workaround is to have the other logic wanted to perform inside an ActivityTrigger and then use it from the Main Orchestrator.